# Convert linearGradient to CSS background

Tags: css, svg, linear-gradients

I have an SVG with the following:

```
<linearGradient id="path-2_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-275.652" y1="410.9046" x2="-275.0113" y2="412.0578" gradientTransform="matrix(46 0 0 -45.9998 12690 18947.9102)">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(248, 64, 24);"></stop>
    <stop offset="0.6458" style="stop-color: rgb(248, 64, 24); stop-opacity: 0.6009;"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color: rgb(248, 64, 24); stop-opacity: 0.2527;"></stop>
</linearGradient>
```

I'm attempting to convert it to a CSS background, but it isn't quite coming out right:

```
background: linear-gradient(
  rgb(248, 64, 24) 0%
  rgba(248, 64, 24 0.60) 65%,
  rgba(248, 64, 24 0.25) 100%,
 );
```

The `gradientTransform` is doing something, but I'm not sure as to what, and how to replicate it in my CSS style.

Comment: if you don't add the SVG tag you will not summon the SVG wizards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the final gradient you need to first consider `x1/y1/x2/y2` that are defining the direction (until now it's easy) then you need to be able to understand the transformation done to the gradient after using [`gradientTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientTransform) which is not trivial. So either you are an SVG and Mathematician guru and you can do the calculation to find the values you need to use in the CSS or you use a tool that can convert your gradient (like http://gradientfinder.com/) or you look at the gradient and you try to approximate it.

Personally I can do the approximation:

```css
.box {
  background: 
  linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(248, 64, 24) 30%, rgba(248, 64, 24, 0.60) 42%, rgba(248, 64, 24, 0.25) 50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<svg height="150" width="400">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="path-2_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-275.652" y1="410.9046" x2="-275.0113" y2="412.0578" gradientTransform="matrix(46 0 0 -45.9998 12690 18947.9102)">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(248, 64, 24);"></stop>
    <stop offset="0.6458" style="stop-color: rgb(248, 64, 24); stop-opacity: 0.6009;"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color: rgb(248, 64, 24); stop-opacity: 0.2527;"></stop>
</linearGradient>

  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="150" fill="url(#path-2_2_)" />
</svg>

<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
body{
  background-image: url(/*link to your svg file*/)
}
```

I hope that I helped ;)

Comment: You didn't answer the question or provide a meaningful alternative.